# guidance to develop backbone application

Tags: backbone.js

I am very new to backbone. I have to develope an application which stores the orders and when we save the information, it displays the information in table. Can you suggest me how to build the appli cation?

Comment: This is probably a bit too broad for Stack Overflow - have a look at "too broad" here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions. You should try a search for "Backbone Tutorials" - eg https://backbonetutorials.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do this tutorial it may help

http://todomvc.com/examples/backbone/